# mysql: Insert ~ on duplicate key (multiple unique, not pimary key) update. does not work

Tags: mysql

```
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `uniq_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `uniq_cat` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    );

 ALTER TABLE `table`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `uniq_id` (`uniq_id`,`uniq_cat`);

 INSERT INTO `table` (uniq_id, uniq_cat, value) 
 VALUES ("1", "1", "ONE") 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value;

 INSERT INTO `table` (uniq_id, uniq_cat, value) 
 VALUES ("1", "1", "TWO") 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value;

 SELECT * FROM `table`
```

gives value = "ONE"
WHY??? 
On second insert it should be overwritten from "ONE" to "TWO" but this does not happen

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e443e/1

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value;` means to do nothing is there ever is a value named `value`. This is why your insert doesn't overwrite the datas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax issue with your `insert into...ON DUPLICATE KEY`. Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO `table` (uniq_id, uniq_cat, value) 
 VALUES ("1", "1", "ONE") 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = values(value);

 INSERT INTO `table` (uniq_id, uniq_cat, value) 
 VALUES ("1", "1", "TWO") 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = values(value);
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e293ea/1)**

Comment: I don't understood why my solution does not work, but it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: @scrache:- You are welcome. Check the line: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = values(value);` that is the difference and that is the reason why your code is not working